# How to simulate data matrix based on 5-point Likert response in R

Tags: r, likert

I need your help. Could someone tell me how to simulate matrix data based on Likert-scale response (5-point Likert scale – 1-Extremely Unhappy, 2-Unhappy,3-Neutral,4-Happy,5-Extremely Happy). I need to simulate artificial data for 5 different constructs/domains with 10 items each for sample size, N=100. I also assumed each of the items has factor loading 0.7. I already installed fabricatr, likert and psych packages and I was trying to create this simulated data but wasn’t able to do it. Could one help me how to get this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is your variable distributed? Can you post some plots or tables?

Comment: If I assumed my variables are normally distributed, how to simulate the data?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `sample` function in R, to fill matrices to your
specifications.

- The first argument of `sample` specifies the Likert choices:
  `1:5`;
- The second argument specifies the number of values to be returned;
- The third argument should be `rep=T` because the Likert choices can each
  be chosen more than once; and
- The fourth argument is a probability vector
  giving the frequency with which each Likert value is chosen. (The probability vector can give proportions; R will turn them into probabilities if they don't sum to 1.)

I will make a matrix with 10 columns and 100 rows. The first five columns
have different probability vectors than than the last five. This is smaller than the matrix you need, but you can extend the procedure as required.

```
## PROGRAM
set.seed(711)  # for reproducibility
A = matrix(sample(1:5, 5*100, rep=T, prob=c(3,3,3,1,1)), byrow=T, nrow=100)
B = matrix(sample(1:5, 5*100, rep=T, prob=c(1,1,2,4,6)), byrow=T, nrow=100)
head(A);  head(B)   # view first six rows of each matrix
DTA = cbind(A, B)   # glue two matrices together to make 10 x 100
head(DTA)           # view first six rows of big matrix
```

.

```
## OUTPUT
 head(A);  head(B)   # view first six rows of each matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3    3    3    2    3
[2,]    1    3    1    2    2  
[3,]    1    2    5    5    4
[4,]    4    2    2    4    2
[5,]    1    3    3    1    1
[6,]    1    2    2    1    5

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    2    4    5    5    4
[2,]    5    2    5    2    1
[3,]    1    4    5    3    4
[4,]    3    4    3    3    4
[5,]    2    4    4    4    5
[6,]    5    5    4    3    1

DTA = cbind(A, B)   # glue two matrices together to make 10 x 100      
head(DTA)           # view first six rows of big matrix
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    3    3    3    2    3    2    4    5    5     4
[2,]    1    3    1    2    2    5    2    5    2     1
[3,]    1    2    5    5    4    1    4    5    3     4
[4,]    4    2    2    4    2    3    4    3    3     4
[5,]    1    3    3    1    1    2    4    4    4     5
[6,]    1    2    2    1    5    5    5    4    3     1
```

.

```
## SUMMARIES
mean(A);  mean(B)
[1] 2.406   # grumpier
[1] 3.906   # cheerier

table(A)
A
  1   2   3   4   5 
141 143 127  50  39 
table(B)
B
  1   2   3   4   5 
 41  33  74 136 216
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response. But may I know what is mean by the argument you stated below:                                                                                     
 "The fourth argument is a probability vector giving the frequency with which each Likert value is chosen. (The probability vector can give proportions; R will turn them into probabilities if they don't sum to 1.)"

Comment: For example, my vector $(3,3,3,1,1)$ is interpreted as $(3/11. 3/11, 3/11, 1/11, 1/11).$ This should get you started. Hope you can figure out the 'factor loading' part; not familiar with simulating that.

Comment: Thank you, you help me a lot